# Powershell Import IPs into Exchange Receive Connector

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have this Powershell script below that basically works:

```
$ReceiveConnector = Get-ReceiveConnector "Name of Receive Connector"
Get-Content C:list.txt | foreach {$ReceiveConnector.RemoteIPRanges += "$_"}
Set-ReceiveConnector $ReceiveConnector -RemoteIPRanges $ReceiveConnector.RemoteIPRanges
```

My issue is that we have 6 receive connectors on the target machine.  The list of IPs in the list.txt file is an export from 2 legacy servers we are decomming.  The script fails because of the 1K IPs in the list there are some that already exist on the target machine in a different receive connector. Can the script be adjusted so that as it runs through the list of IPs and if see it exist already in a different RC it bypasses and keeps importing the unique IPs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic, but working scenario:

Create a cycle for each item in RemoteIPRanges array and add each during the cycle. This way, if the item already exist in the list on the new connector, you'll just receive an error for a certain IP.

Should look like this:

```
$ReceiveConnector.RemoteIPRanges | foreach {set-receiveconnector NewReceiveConnector -RemoteIPRanges @{add=$_}}
```

Please check it on a test item first.